# Php5.6. linux. ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, ubuntu, установка

В **Ubuntu 16.04(mate)** попытался установить **php5.6**, добавил репозиторий

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

обновил:

```
sudo apt update
```

попытался установить:

```
sudo apt install php5.6
```

и получил вот это:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Заметьте, выбирается «php5.6-json» для regex «php5.6»
Заметьте, выбирается «php5.6-common» для regex «php5.6»
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
```

что с этим делать не представляю. Был установлен **nginx-** удалил. Удалил и сгенерировал на одном из сайтов новый **source.list** и добавил снова репозиторий, ничего не помогло. 
По умолчанию установлен **php7.0**

Comment: Может, надо сперва снести 7.0, хотя оно и не пишет, что уже установлена более новая версия пакета?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать стандартный репозиторий Ubuntu, тем более php5.6 там есть.

Answer (score 0):

После добавления

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial main
```

все начало работать